# Charts (C# WinForms) - How to set X label

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm working with C# Winforms, using a chart with 25000 points data source (that can't be changed). The data represents samples in time, and every 1 second has 5000 samples. My chart shows 5 seconds.
My X bars (columns) is spaced between 1000 points (every 200ms). But I needed the Label (0, 1, 2...) to be shown just for each 5000 points (each second).

The image below shows what I need and have been trying to do unsuccessfully:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5RMk.png)

My code for the chart:

```
const int SAMPLES_PER_SECOND = 5000;
const int CHART_SECONDS_TO_SHOW = 5;
const int SAMPLES_PER_CHART = SAMPLES_PER_SECOND * CHART_SECONDS_TO_SHOW;

chart1.Series[0] = new Series();
chart1.Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(Enumerable.Range(0, SAMPLES_PER_CHART).ToArray(), array1); //array1 is my array with data (25000 points)

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = SAMPLES_PER_SECOND/5;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled=false;
```

Can anyone help me how I could to that? Thanks a lot!